# each function adding all content to global variable rather than 1 per loop

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a each function as below

```
function staffProfileTechnology() {
    $('.staff-profile').addClass('staffProfileTechnology');

    var staffTechnologyBioContent = $('.staffProfileTechnology').find('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl07__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField').html();

    $('.staffProfileTechnology .col-sm-9 #accordion h3').each(function(){

        var staffTechnologyAccordionTitle = $(this).text();
        var staffTechnologyAccordionContent = $(this).closest('#accordion').find('.ms-rtestate-field').html();
        
        console.log(staffTechnologyAccordionTitle+':'+staffTechnologyAccordionContent+',');
    });
};
```

In console I see that 'staffTechnologyAccordionTitle' appears once as it should, but with the 'staffTechnologyAccordionContent',  I have the same content, rather than it moving to the next iteration, which the title does correctly.

So I get a new title but the same content, as below.

```
Teaching : <p>​For 6 years Jon was the principal lecturer in Control Engineering at the RAF College Cranwell where he taught post graduate engineering officers up to MSc. Within his own company, Muretex, he designed and delivered a module on Avionic Systems for 3rd students on the Aerospace Engineering course at the University of Leicester. As Dean of the school h​e oversees the broadening of the school of technologies portfolio of programmes to include Integrated Masters courses in engineering and Degree Apprenticeships as well as additional computer science related courses.&nbsp;<br></p>

Research : <p>​For 6 years Jon was the principal lecturer in Control Engineering at the RAF College Cranwell where he taught post graduate engineering officers up to MSc. Within his own company, Muretex, he designed and delivered a module on Avionic Systems for 3rd students on the Aerospace Engineering course at the University of Leicester. As Dean of the school h​e oversees the broadening of the school of technologies portfolio of programmes to include Integrated Masters courses in engineering and Degree Apprenticeships as well as additional computer science related courses.&nbsp;<br></p>
```

This is what the code looks like in console

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Teaching</h3>
<div class="ms-rtestate-field"><p>​For 6 years Jon was the principal lecturer in Control Engineering at the RAF College Cranwell where he taught post graduate engineering officers up to MSc. Within his own company, Muretex, he designed and delivered a module on Avionic Systems for 3rd students on the Aerospace Engineering course at the University of Leicester. As Dean of the school h​e oversees the broadening of the school of technologies portfolio of programmes to include Integrated Masters courses in engineering and Degree Apprenticeships as well as additional computer science related courses.</p></div>

<h3>Research</h3>
<div class="ms-rtestate-field"><p>​Jon has had commercial success with his own company Muretex, winning significant, nationally competed, research grant funding; including Innovate UK funding for Robotics and Autonomous Systems. He has international contacts and reach, having proposed and chaired 2 European research action groups over 8 years and been invited to deliver a NATO lecture series on autonomy. His current research interests lie at the intersection of systems engineering practices and the capture of requirements for human-machine teaming in autonomous systems to ensure that levels of autonomy are appropriate to meet overall system needs.</p></div>
```

Comment: `var` is scoped to the nearest `function`.  `let` is scoped to the nearest `{}`.

Comment: Do you specifically mean that `$(this).closest('#accordion').find('.ms-rtestate-field').text()` is returning more content than you expect?  What HTML is it querying, and what specific result are you expecting?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a *complete* sample, including relevant HTML that *demonstrates* the issue?  See [MCVE]

Comment: As indicated above: `$(this).closest('#accordion').find('.ms-rtestate-field').text();` will get all texts for all `.ms-rtestate-field`s - assuming there's one `#accordion` on the page, this will get the same values each time - likely the source of your "all content".  You likely need a different navigation to get the "current" text, but without HTML we can't help you much.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post to better reflect where I am and hopefully the extra information makes it more understandable

Comment: `$(this).closest('#accordion').find('.ms-rtestate-field').html();` -> `$(this).next().html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to find the *immediate next* instance of `.ms-rtestate-field` for each `<h3>`.  Currently what you're doing is travering up to a common parent and finding *all* instances:

```
$(this).closest('#accordion').find('.ms-rtestate-field')
```

But if `this` represents the `<h3>` element then you can use something like [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the immediate next matching element.  For example:

```js
$('#accordion h3').each(function(){
  var staffTechnologyAccordionContent = $(this).next('.ms-rtestate-field').html();
  console.log(staffTechnologyAccordionContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Teaching</h3>
  <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
    <p>For 6 years Jon was the principal lecturer...</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Research</h3>
  <div class="ms-rtestate-field">
    <p>Jon has had commercial success with...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```